# При нажатии на кнопку нужно обновить текущую страницу

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создал программу, имитирующую авторизацию. Пользователь вводит своё имя и пароль, после чего нажима на кнопку "Войти" скрипт обращается к моему словарю и сравнивает данные. Если они совпадают, то должен произойти эффект перемещения на новую страницу (то есть текущая информация должна пропасть и появится пустой фон (любой фон, на котором я напишу текст)).

!!!!! Помогите сделать этот переход или обновление страницы !!!!!

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

dict_pass= {
    'Миша':'415'
    }

root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("1300x900")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=323, height=576, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)




my_canvas.create_text(370,200, text='Пользователь', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')
my_canvas.create_text(420,300, text='Пароль', fill='Black', font='Verdana 22')


name_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
name_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 190, anchor="nw", window=name_entry)

pass_entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_window = my_canvas.create_window(500, 290, anchor="nw", window=pass_entry)


btn = Button(root, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, bg='White', fg='Black')
btn_window = my_canvas.create_window(420,370, anchor='nw', window=btn)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `.pack_forget()`.
Вот пример:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

dict_pass = {
    'Миша': '415'
}


def log_in():
    try:
        if dict_pass[name_entry.get()] == pass_entry.get():
            frame.pack_forget()
            frame_log_inned.pack()

    except KeyError:
        pass


root = Tk()
root.title('Авторизация')
root.geometry("640x480")

root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

frame = Frame(root)

Label(frame, text='Пользователь').pack()

name_entry = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
name_entry.pack()

Label(frame, text='Пароль').pack()

pass_entry = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=13, fg='Black', bg='White')
pass_entry.pack()

btn = Button(frame, text='Вход', font='Helvetica 18', width=10, bg='White', fg='Black', command=log_in)
btn.pack(pady=10)

frame.pack()

frame_log_inned = Frame(root)

Label(frame_log_inned, text='Успех').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь